# Problems with UIImagePickerController cancel button not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an universal app that allows to select an image from the device photo library for later manipulation, the code works fine on the iPad but nothing happens on the iPhone, not even the cancel button and after an image is selected nothing happens neither here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)grabImage:(id)sender
{
    if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
{
    imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [imgPicker setDelegate:self];

    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imgPicker];
    [popover setDelegate:self];

    CGPoint position        = [view1.superview convertPoint:view1.frame.origin toView:nil];
    CGRect popOverFrame     = CGRectMake( position.x, position.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height );

    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:popOverFrame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:nil animated:NO];
    [popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 480)];
    [imgPicker release];
}
else
{
    imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imgPicker.delegate = self;
    imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
    [imgPicker release];
}
}


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    pickedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

CGImageRef imgRef = pickedImage.CGImage;

    app->setImage( pickedImage, CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef) );

    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

// Enable texture siwth after an image has been loaded
[textureSwitch setEnabled:YES];
[textureSwitch setOn:YES];
app->isTextureDrawingOn     = [textureSwitch isOn];

[fillsSwitch setOn:NO];
app->isFillsDrawingOn       = [fillsSwitch isOn];

    if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
{
    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
ofLog(OF_LOG_VERBOSE, "cancel after selection");
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
[[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
{
        [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }

ofLog(OF_LOG_VERBOSE, "did cancel");
}
```

Comment: Check Did you add uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate in your interface file??

Comment: Though this won't fix your problem, you should switch to using `presentViewController:animated:completion:` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` in place of `presentModalViewController:animated:` and `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`, as the latter two are deprecated (see [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

Comment: After reading all suggestions using [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; does fix the problem to some extend but what happens now is that the view that have the button to open the image picker disappears, any ideas?

Comment: solve the issue my vis were push to the top, all I had to do was re-aling everything on cancel

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of using below code.

```
[[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Try this code

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and also check did you add `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` in your interface file.

**SOLUTION: (From my comment)**

Try this `[self.imgPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`
This will work.

**For iOS 7:** To dismiss a present view controller

```
[self.imgPicker dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: NULL];
```

Comment: Using self makes all the views to disappear all I need is to cancel the image picker view, it does work fine on the iPad but it doesn't work on the iPhone

Comment: then try this [self.imgPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: For iOS 7, this seems to work:      [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: NULL];

Answer (score 8):

Add `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` in your interface file

and then implement this code in your `.m` file

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

i hope it's solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

check viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear methods of your parent controller which calls the picker. On iPhone this methods will be called after picker view disappeared. They will not be called after popover disappeared on iPad. I just found error in my code where i set nil to ivar for picked image in viewWillAppear. it take me two days to understand what is happened ;)
Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

An easiest solution:

Add UIImagePickerControllerDelegate in your interface file

and then implement this code in your .m file

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [picker  dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0**

Thanks to MBH this worked for me in my Xcode 8 and iOS 10 project:

```
internal func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController){
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For closing it in Swift:**

After adding those protocols to you ViewController: `UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

```
internal func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController){
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: @RohitGupta I tested it and it works fine. since i implemented the delegate `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` on my ViewController